# Unable to locate dozer mapping file dozerBeanMapping.xml in the classpath

Tags: hibernate, gwt, dozer

I've started using Dozer to map my domain objects to the DTO's on the client side. Unfortunately it says that can't find dozerBeanMapping.xml on my classpath witch I double checked and is there. I also checked that the the file is deployed on classes folder along with the other files.

I putted the file in my main package along with the .gwt.xml file used by gwt.

I get the following stacktrace:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.Long com.ohapp.webmetalmore.client.DataService.saveAlbum(com.ohapp.webmetalmore.shared.dto.AlbumDTO)' threw an unexpected exception: org.dozer.MappingException: Unable to locate dozer mapping file [dozerBeanMapping.xml] in the classpath!
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: org.dozer.MappingException: Unable to locate dozer mapping file [dozerBeanMapping.xml] in the classpath!
    at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:87)
    at org.dozer.util.MappingValidator.validateURL(MappingValidator.java:63)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadFromFiles(DozerBeanMapper.java:225)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:209)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.initMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:315)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:192)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)
    at com.ohapp.webmetalmore.server.DataServiceImpl.saveAlbum(DataServiceImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
```

The project is being developed in eclipse with maven (version 3.0), gwt (version 2.5.1), hibernate (4.2.7.Final) and Dozer (version 5.4.0).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using another previous version of dozer, but anyway, I have dozerBeanMapping.xml in:

```
src/main/resources/
```